# How to Combine dates and time in separate fields in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ssrs-2008

Table :

```
schedule_id job_id      next_run_date   next_run_time
------------------------------------------------------
221         D23EA7B2    20151005            90000
222         18EDFB21    20151020            90000
242         90283725    20151001            170000
239         4B69C670    20151011            90000
```

Result :

```
schedule_id  job_id      next_run_date_Time 
--------------------------------------------
221         D23EA7B2    2015-10-05 09:00 AM
222         18EDFB21    2015-10-20 09:00 AM
242         90283725    2015-10-01 05:00 PM
239         4B69C670    2015-10-11 09:00 AM
```

How to join `next_run_date` and `next_run_time` together as a single column?

### My Query used in SSRS 2008

```
    SELECT c.Name AS ReportName,[LastRunTime],
'Next Run Date' = CASE next_run_date WHEN 0 THEN null ELSE
substring(convert(varchar(15),next_run_date),1,4) + '/' +
substring(convert(varchar(15),next_run_date),5,2) + '/' +
substring(convert(varchar(15),next_run_date),7,2)
END,
--Need to add next_run_date_Time here
FROM 
dbo.[Catalog] c
INNER JOIN dbo.[Subscriptions] S ON c.ItemID = S.Report_OID
INNER JOIN dbo.ReportSchedule R ON S.SubscriptionID = R.SubscriptionID
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs J ON Convert(nvarchar(128),R.ScheduleID) = J.name
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules JS ON J.job_id = JS.job_id
ORDER BY S.LastRunTime DESC
```

Comment: Do you want to join them physically by modifying the table? or just a query result?

Comment: what is the data type of  "next_run_date" & "next_run_time" ? `varchar` ? & what you have tried?

Comment: Table in SSRS , Table name : msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules

Comment: Hi @Sac Datatypes are int

Comment: Hi @RacilHilan Only result want to join

Comment: OK, see my answer for both `varchar` and `number`.

Comment: @RacilHilan How can i add in my above query? I have used Next Run Time and Next Run Date Separate

Comment: Simply replace the `msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules` with my sub-query and use my conversion method to combine the two columns. See my updated answer.

Comment: @RacilHilan Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both are `varchar`, try this:

```
SELECT schedule_id, job_id,
       CONVERT(datetime, next_run_date, 112)
       + CONVERT(time,
                 SUBSTRING(next_run_time, 1, LEN(next_run_time) - 4) + ':'
                 + LEFT(RIGHT(next_run_time, 4), 2) + ':'
                 + RIGHT(next_run_time, 2),
               114) AS next_run_date_Time
FROM my_table
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d827/3)

If those fields are numbers, you can convert them in a sub-query first and then apply the same query above:

```
SELECT schedule_id, job_id,
       CONVERT(datetime, next_run_date, 112)
       + CONVERT(time,
                 SUBSTRING(next_run_time, 1, LEN(next_run_time) - 4) + ':'
                 + LEFT(RIGHT(next_run_time, 4), 2) + ':'
                 + RIGHT(next_run_time, 2),
               114) AS next_run_date_Time
FROM (SELECT schedule_id, job_id
           , CAST(next_run_date AS VARCHAR(8)) AS next_run_date
           , CAST(next_run_time AS VARCHAR(6)) AS next_run_time
      FROM my_table) AS t
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d46d/5)

**EDIT** you can update your query to use this concept like this:

```
SELECT c.Name AS ReportName,[LastRunTime],
       CONVERT(datetime, next_run_date, 112)
       + CONVERT(time,
                 SUBSTRING(next_run_time, 1, LEN(next_run_time) - 4) + ':'
                 + LEFT(RIGHT(next_run_time, 4), 2) + ':'
                 + RIGHT(next_run_time, 2),
               114) AS 'Next Run Date'
FROM 
dbo.[Catalog] c
INNER JOIN dbo.[Subscriptions] S ON c.ItemID = S.Report_OID
INNER JOIN dbo.ReportSchedule R ON S.SubscriptionID = R.SubscriptionID
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs J ON Convert(nvarchar(128),R.ScheduleID) = J.name
INNER JOIN (SELECT schedule_id, job_id
                 , CAST(next_run_date AS VARCHAR(8)) AS next_run_date
                 , CAST(next_run_time AS VARCHAR(6)) AS next_run_time
            FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules) AS JS ON J.job_id = JS.job_id
ORDER BY S.LastRunTime DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
-- Create sample table and data 
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  next_run_date char(8),
  next_run_time varchar(6)
)

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
(20151005, 93020),
(20151001, 170000)
```

using cte1 to pad next_run_time with a leading zero if needed,
and using cte2 to break the string to a "normal" time representation:

```
;with cte1 as 
(
    select next_run_date,
           right('000000'+ next_run_time, 6) as run_time_base
    FROM tbl
), cte2 as
(
    select next_run_date, 
           left(run_time_base, 2) + ':' + 
           substring(run_time_base, 3, 2) + ':' +
           right(run_time_base, 2) as run_time
    from cte1 
)

select cast(next_run_date as datetime) + cast(run_time as datetime) as run_datetime
from cte2

-- clean up
drop table tbl
```

Results:

```
run_datetime
-----------------------
2015-10-05 09:30:20.000
2015-10-01 17:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that `next_run_date` & `next_run_time`, I have written query here which will give your desired output..

```
select 
    schedule_id
   ,job_id 
   ,convert(datetime, 
      convert(varchar, convert(datetime, next_run_date, 112), 111)
      + ' ' + substring(REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(next_run_time)) + next_run_time, 1, 2)
      + ':' + substring(REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(next_run_time)) + next_run_time, 3, 2)
      + ':' + substring(REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(next_run_time)) + next_run_time, 5, 2)
    ) as next_run_date_Time 
 from TableName
```

Here is the [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9678/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest option, assuming both are `varchars` to begin with, is:

```
dateadd(HH, cast(left(time, len(time) - 4) as int), cast(date as datetime))
```

Convert the `varchar` date to a `datetime` format, which will default to midnight on the date, then add the number of hours specified by the time.  The syntax above assumes times are always on the hour - if not, add minutes as necessary.

Once in `datetime`, you can use `convert` to specify any display format you like.